# 500 server error in Laravel mail send

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

My `.env` file looks like the below configuration. When I send mail it shows a 500 server error. It works fine in local `xampp` server (where `APP_ENV=local`). There is no error shown in log file also, but when I change the option:

```
'pretend' => true,
```

then log file write some text like

> production.INFO: Pretending to mail message to: sales@accezatech.com

Can anyone help me please to find where I made a mistake?

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=DDPTFVZSt4zikAZXZEp7Z0bebKQA1Mug

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=ferdosh_acceza_db
DB_USERNAME=ferdosh_dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=**********

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.accezatech.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME=visitor@accezatech.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
```

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error there will be a reason for it, when you say you have checked the logs have you checked both laravel and the server logs?

Comment: in hostgator cPanel i have checked log file but there is nothing. i also set 777 permission to storage directory. do you have any farther idea regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `'pretend' => false` instead of `true`

Answer (score -1):

Your `APP_DEBUG=true` so it should print debug message. If not then try to set storage folder permission to 777. Maybe log file is not writable.